# how does postgreSQL 8 handle concurrency control

Tags: postgresql

Am using postgreSQL 8 to create a database. I have noticed that it migt suffer a problem with concurrency control.
1. please explain to me how does postgreSQL 8 handle concurrency control?
2. when comparing MY SQL with postgreSQL which of these is best to handle concurrency control.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it suffers problems with concurrency control if you know how to use PostgreSQL's specific implementation of concurrency control. Throw out everything you think you know about concurrency control in other database systems and start with a fresh mind and read the pg documentation on how it handles it.  Don't even try to compare other mvcc databases just start fresh.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL 8 does not exist, you have 8.0, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3 and 8.4. All different major versions. Version 9.0 will be released this month.

PostgreSQL uses MVCC (Multiversion Concurrency Control), as described in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/mvcc.html

MySQL uses per engine a different stategy, innoDB also uses MVCC. Major difference will be that in PostgreSQL, everything is transaction safe, including DDL like ALTER TABLE.

> I have noticed that it migt suffer a
>   problem with concurrency control.

What did you notice? MVCC is a smart system, not a perfect system. But it's good enough for many databases, like Oracle and Firebird.